# How can I change file name in blogger?

Tags: blogger, blogspot

I've a blogspot account and I'm running a blog. The problem is i'd not change the file name like `http://some-domain.blogspot.com/i-can't-change-this-part`. You know the thing that specifies the file name, I want to make it more SEO optimized. So how do i change that?

Answer (score 0):

For `new` posts,you have an option to customise them

On the right,Click on links and `custom permalink`

[image]
<sub>(source: [ctrlv.in](https://img.ctrlv.in/img/14/03/17/53268fccc5f93.jpg))</sub>

Comment: By looking at the OP's Question, He has no idea about the recent `Search Preferences` in Blogger. so you should add `How to get the Permalink` option enabled in Blogger aswell.

Answer (score 0):

this is exactly known as a permalink structure

you can not change the blogger permalink structure. Default structure is www.domain.com/year/month/**post-name**.html

you can customize "post-name" just find permalink option while adding **NEW POST**. **( /year/month/** will remain their their is not as such provision is provided in to blogger CMS)